# jsoup error fetching URL. Status=503 only on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jsoup

when using Jsoup to connect to https://rateyourmusic.com through localhost it works just fine, however, on Heroku, I always receive error 503, even using an userAgent

```
String url = "https://rateyourmusic.com/charts/top/album/2016";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0").followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

Heroku log:

```
2019-10-26T23:20:06.674831+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/searchTrack?searchRadio=2&playlistName=&searchNameArtist=&searchNameAlbum=https%3A%2F%2Frateyourmusic.com%2Fcharts%2Ftop%2Falbum%2F2016&amountChart=3&amountRadio=3" host=gettoptracks.herokuapp.com request_id=026060b4-71ab-4510-9809-fe5cffc3f325 fwd="176.32.19.237" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=313ms status=200 bytes=11534 protocol=https

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.670478+00:00 app[web.1]: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=https://rateyourmusic.com/charts/top/album/2016

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.670652+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:760)

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.670655+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:705)

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.670661+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:295)

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.670663+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:284)

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.670668+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.spotifyapi.demo.service.ServiceApiImpl.getRYM(ServiceApiImpl.java:561)

   ...

    2019-10-26T23:20:06.671189+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I try to connect to another website on Heroku using Jsoup it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the request require an API token?

Comment: No token required

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, the application works in other servers, but in Heroku using Jsoup it returns 503. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @RobsonCassol no, even then using VPN on Jsoup it doesn't work so I gave up.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: no, i've tried nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem in your code. The error `503` is returned by the server. That means there's something the server didn't like about your request or your client and refused to return normal response. Probably Heroku is the reason and it's blocked to avoid scraping their site.
To be 100% sure you can use something else to download contents of this page to avoid using Jsoup use plain HttpClient or even pure Java: 
[How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)
If the result is the same that confirms they block Heroku. You may try connecting through some proxy to overcome this.